# Quadratic equation system solving analytically or numerically

Tags: r, matlab, quadratic-form

I have such a nonlinear equation system

$x_i=\frac{\sum_{j\neq i}a_{ij}\times\sum_{k\neq i}x_k}{\sum_{k\neq i}x_k-\sum_{j\neq i}a_{ij}}$

where $a_{ij}$s are known coefficients in $[0,1]$. And $x_i$s are variables and have non-negative constrain. All the indicies are in $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$ for some very large, known integer $N$.

It seems to be quadratic for $x_i$s. Is there any way to solve it analytically? If not, can we solve it numerically? Or will it be helpful to convert it to an optimization problem? I have experience in MATLAB and R, but I have not yet used them to solve non-linear equation system.

I find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046256/solving-a-non-linear-multivariable-system-of-equations) post helpful, but I prefer an analytical solution since there might be 10k+ variables.